# When I'm working on live repo. How to push files/directories (Like Each every time or all in one time)?

Tags: java, spring, git, github

**Push Problem**

> add,commit,push ---->Boom....(double folder on git-hub)

I am confused that firstly i had commit and push whole project to Git-
hub but now i have done many changes in my local repository but when i am pushing it so it's pushing whole directory as second so on my Git-hub repository there has been second folder created of second push why its not pushing on working first repository  ?????

- git and git hub

Comment: Are you adding, committing and pushing from inside the directory?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "double folder", but Git doesn't push *files*, nor *folders*, at all: Git pushes entire commits. Each commit has a full snapshot of every file; the file's names include embedded slashes, so `path/to/file` is not a file named `file` in a folder named `to` in a folder named `path`, but rather just a file named `path/to/file`. (Technically the embedded slashes go in Git's *index*, but that's how Git manipulates the files. It has to folder-ize them to make your OS happy, but internally, it has them with slashes.)

Comment: 1.i commited and push just 1 file in my directory like : src/main/hello.javawhat if i made many other files without commit but now i need to just push one file update